# Retrieving xml file

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to retrieve contents of xml file but no content is retrieved.
My xml file is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
 <?xml-stylesheet href="mobiles.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
 <db>
 <mobiles>
 <name><h3><a href="http://www.digitaltrends.com/cell-phone-reviews/
 motorola-moto-g-review/">Motorola Moto G</a></h3></name>

    <screen_size><span class="value">4.5" - 5"</span></screen_size>
 <carrier><span class="value">AT&amp;T</span></carrier>
 <Operating_System><span class="value">Android</span></Operating_System>

</mobiles>
<mobiles>
 <name><h3><a href="http://www.digitaltrends.com/cell-phone-reviews
/apple-iphone-5s-review/">Apple iPhone 5S</a></h3></name>

    <screen_size><span class="value">4" - 4.5"</span></screen_size>
<carrier><span class="value">AT&amp;T</span></carrier>
<Operating_System><span class="value">iOS</span></Operating_System>

</mobiles>
<mobiles>
<name><h3><a href="http://www.digitaltrends.com/cell-phone-reviews/lg-g2-review/">
LG G2</a></h3></name>

    <screen_size><span class="value">5" - 5.5"</span></screen_size>
<carrier><span class="value">AT&amp;T</span></carrier>
<Operating_System><span class="value">Android</span></Operating_System>

</mobiles>
</db>
```

And code which i am using to retrieve the contents is:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>

 <?php
 $xml=simplexml_load_file("mobiles.xml");
 echo "<h2>Top 3 smartphones of the month</h2>";


foreach ($xml->children() as $child){

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$child->name."</td>";
echo "<td>".$child->screen_size."</td>";
echo "<td>".$child->carrier."</td>";
echo "<td>".$child->Operating_System."</td>";

echo "</tr>";
}
 ?>

</body>
</html>
```

I am not able to figure out the error.What's the error in it?

Comment: PHP close tag. `?>` is missing.

Comment: @MeNa done that..still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
foreach ($xml->children() as $child){
```

To

```
foreach ($xml as $child){
```

Also, you are not accessing the correct element for echoing. For example you should be doing something like:-

```
echo "<td>".$child->name->h3->a."</td>";
```

Because each html element is a SimpleXml element;

http://php.net/simplexml

Answer (score 1):

You haven't closed the php tag. Try;

```
echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```